# C Adding two big number by char array

Tags: c

I need to add two big number sized 0-100 digits with `char` array and i dont know how can i deal with the empty array cell..

How can i compare the cell of array with unassigned number. i want to divide the case into two part.

```
bigM[i] == empty cell, directly put bigN[i] + carry in to sum[i] 
bigN[i] == empty cell, directly put bigM[i] + carry  in to sum[i]

//
// AddTwoBigNumbers: to sum up two big numbers represented as digits in a char clear_char_array
//
// input:  char bigN[], char bigM[]:  two large numbers
// output the sum as a big number in the input array char sum[]
void AddTwoBigNumbers(char bigN[], char bigM[], char sum[])
{
    reverseArray(bigN, 0, 100);
    reverseArray(bigM, 0, 100);

    //calculation
    int carry = 0;
    for(int i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int sum_two = (bigN[i] - '0') + (bigM[i] - '0') + carry;
        sum[i] = sum_two % 10 + '0';
        carry = sum_two / 10;
    }

    reverseArray(sum, 0, 100);
}
```

[ideone link](https://ideone.com/Qa0aAu)

Comment: The actual problem here is how to represent a big number in C rather than doing the addition on two such numbers..

Comment: I feel so lost... can you give me some suggestion on how to make it works?

Comment: So your arrays _must_ be 100 digits. Then the for loop should start at `i=99` because arrays in C are from 0..N-1.

Comment: I think that first you should normalize the arrays. That is, add `'0'` characters to the left. Then reverse the arrays. Then do the calculation. Finally reverse the result. For "beauty" eliminate '0's at the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counter for each array could be used.
When a counter reaches the end of an array, that `if` block will no longer execute.
When both counters reach the end of the array, break out of the loop.

```
//calculation
int i = 0;
int carry = 0;
int index = 0;
int next = 0;
while ( 1) {
    int sum_two = carry;
    if ( bigM[index]) {// not zero
        sum_two += bigM[index] - '0';
        index++
    }
    if ( bigN[next]) {//not zero
        sum_two += bigN[next] - '0';
        next++;
    }
    sum[i] = sum_two % 10 + '0';
    i++;
    carry = sum_two / 10;
    if ( bigM[index] == 0 && bigN[next] == 0) {//both are zero
        break;
    }
}
if ( carry) {
    sum[i] = carry + '0';
    i++;
}
sum[i] = 0;//terminate with zero
```